# Server resource available to browser and Postman but could not resolve in cURL

Tags: docker, curl, traefik

I have a call in Postman that produces the following response:

```
Hostname: 4534319174a2
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test.docker.localhost
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Postman-Token: 4a75ed35-fc23-4061-8f42-8abc32ba33b6
X-Forwarded-Host: test.docker.localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: 891f07ca9b9c
```

When I export the Postman call to cURL, I get:

```
curl --location --request GET 'test.docker.localhost'
```

When I run the command, it fails:

```
curl --location --request GET 'test.docker.localhost'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test.docker.localhost
```

I can also successfully access `test.docker.localhost` from the browser.

Essentially, it is only cURL that fails to access the resource. On every machine I have used, cURL always behaved like the browser or Postman. What should I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: where are you running curl specifically?

Comment: I am running it from a local iTerm2 terminal (zsh) inside tmux. I have tried running it outside of tmux and I have the same issue. The server is running in docker through traefik.

Comment: That suggests your're running macOS. Are you using Docker Desktop or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have Docker Desktop, correct.

Comment: Hmm, so generally a DNS issue, but if Postman works a really strange one!

Comment: Just to be sure, can you reach other domains from your shell?

Comment: Yes I can! It seems the only DNS entries I cannot cURL from the terminal are the ones running in docker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246698/discussion-between-criztovyl-and-sharp-steel-software).